# ¿Como obtener datos de dos tablas diferentes usando PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola ando intentando obtener datos de dos tablas diferentes en la misma base de datos.

La columna **PERSONAJE** es donde saco el nombre del jugador en la tabla **ct_datos** imagen abajo

[image: Personaje]

De la tabla csstats la columna **NAME** es la misma columna que **PERSONAJE** de la tabla **ct_datos**.

Pero como quiero sacar resultados del jugador por **PERSONAJE** = **NAME** quiero que me arroje los resultados de las demás columnas de csstats dejo marcado en rojo las siguientes columnas que quiero mostrar.

[image: Tabla ct_datos / csstats]

Dejo un código que he probado pero no arroja ningún resultado.

```php
$sentencia2 = $db_ffa->prepare("SELECT * FROM csstats stat INNER JOIN ct_datos em ON stat.skill = em.Rango ORDER BY em.Rango DESC LIMIT 1");
    $sentencia2->execute();
```

Lo quiero colocar dentro del tooltip para que cuando un usuario pase el puntero sobre el nombre del Jugador muestre los datos.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mt-5 mt-md-0">
    <div class="count-box">
        <i class="game-icon game-icon-harry-potter-skull"></i>
        <?php while($row = $sentencia3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){ ?>
        <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="<?php echo $sentencia2; ?>">
            <?php echo $row->Personaje; ?>
        </span>
        <?php } ?>
        <p>Mejor Jugador</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

El nombre del top jugador lo llamo con `$echo $row->Personaje`

```
 $sentencia3 = $db_ffa->prepare("SELECT `Elo`, `Rango`, `Personaje` FROM `ct_datos` ORDER BY `Rango` DESC, `Elo` DESC LIMIT 1");
 $sentencia3->execute();
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda!.

Comment: Esas tablas ¿No deberían estar relacionadas de alguna manera?

Comment: No me deja relacionarlas ```Supports transactions, row-level locking, foreign keys and encryption for tables```

Comment: Si la consulta del `JOIN` no arroja datos es porque no hay datos relacionados que coincidan. Prueba con `LEFT JOIN`, quizá verás ahí resultados. De todos modos, debes asegurarte de las coincidencias. Aunque no haya FK declaradas, cualquier consulta que hagas con `JOIN`, si hay coincidencias, los datos vendrían.

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, como que son varias dudas. Yo te resuelvo una: según yo, tu join no es correcto porque no estás uniendo por la columna personaje. Tu consulta debería ser algo así: `select stat.name, stat.ip, stat.skill, stat.kills, stat.deaths, stat.hs, stat.tks, stat.shots, stat.hits, stat.dmg, stat.bombdef, stat.bombdefused, stat.bombplats, stat.bombexplosions from csstats stat inner join ct_datos em on stat.name=em.Personaje ORDER BY em.Rango DESC LIMIT 1`. Espero que con esto puedas continuar con tu proyecto. Suerte!

Comment: Me ha sido de ayuda @AntonioVenerosoContreras  muchas gracias, igual estaré re organizando las tablas para poderlas relacionarlas así puedo tener mejor control de los resultados.